# Question on Hochreiter's LSTM paper

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, lstm

On the bottom of page 3 of the [LSTM paper](https://www.bioinf.jku.at/publications/older/2604.pdf), it says "This will scale the error by the following factor"

$$\frac{\partial \vartheta_v(t-q)}{\partial\vartheta_u(t)}=\cdots$$

This is very strange to me, as $\vartheta$ is already the error gradient. What does it even mean to differentiate against another error gradient?

Answer (score 1):

We can use $$\vartheta_v(t-q)$$ as the y in a two-dimensional coordinate and $$\vartheta_u(t)$$ as x axis.

[image]

Then if the value of
$$\frac{\partial \vartheta_v(t-q)}{\partial\vartheta_u(t)}$$
is big, it indicates that the slope is deep enough for us to conjecture that the delta value can be transported "in time" from step t to step t - q  seriously(a small increase in x implies a big increase in y). In this case it's very likely that the aftermentioned $$w_{max}$$ in the paper might be bigger than 4, resulting in $$|f^\prime_{l_m}(net_{l_m}(t-m))w_{l_m}l_{m-1}|>1.0$$  for all m, and hence the exploding gradient problem.

Answer (score 0):

By differentiating one error against the other, the author want to exhibit how a change in ϑ_u(t) affects ϑ(t-q). This notion comes from the basic derivative intuition: how does x varies based on y changing values.

He is basically trying to show why the weights tend to vanish(sic.) if you apply BPTT over a RNN.